# php - regex img tags matching

Tags: php, regex

How could I remove all the new lines from all img tags. So for instance if I have:

```
$string = '<img
           src="somelong
            pathimage.jpg"
             height="1" width="10">';
```

so it looks as:

```
$string = '<img src="somelongpathimage.jpg" height="1" width="10">';
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$string = preg_replace("/\n/" , "" , $string);
```

Comment: Surely `preg_replace` is overkill for that?

Comment: `strtr($str, array("\n"=>'',"\r"=>'') )`?

Comment: @Jon - you're absolutely right - it is overkill, but I like regular expressions. In this case, str_replace would have been sufficient. @zzzzBov - strtr() is apparently slower than str_replace - but it does look like a cool alternative http://net-beta.net/ubench/index.php?t=strtr2

Answer (score 2):

Because each OS have different ASCII chars for linebreak:
windows = \r\n
unix = \n
mac = \r

`$string = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n"), "", $string);`

Thread link: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php#73440

Comment: you can drop the `"\r\n"`, as `"\r"` *and* `"\n"` will be converted to the empty string anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you indeed want to leave everything untouched but the guts of the img tags, the code bloats a little:

```
$string = "<html>\n<body>\nmy intro and <img\n src='somelong\npathimage.jpg'\n height='1'   width='10'> and another <img\n src='somelong\npathimage.jpg'\n height='1' width='10'> before end\n</body>\n</html>";
print $string;
print trim_img_tags($string);

function trim_img_tags($string) {
  $tokens = preg_split('/(<img.*?>)/s', $string, 0, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
  for ($i=1; $i<sizeof($tokens); $i=$i+2) {
    $tokens[$i] = preg_replace("/(\n|\r)/", "", $tokens[$i]);
  }
  return implode('', $tokens);
}
```

Before:

```
<html>
<body>
my intro and <img
 src='somelong
pathimage.jpg'
 height='1' width='10'> and another <img
 src='somelong
pathimage.jpg'
 height='1' width='10'> before end
</body>
</html>
```

After:

```
<html>
<body>
my intro and <img src='somelongpathimage.jpg' height='1' width='10'> and another <img src='somelongpathimage.jpg' height='1' width='10'> before end
</body>
</html>
```